# How does ASP.NET MVC OutputCache works when VaryByParam is not specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

What is used as the cache string (key) when `VaryByParam` parameter of the `OutputCache` is not specified?

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30)]
public ActionResult Index(int customerId, Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how the caching behaves when `VaryByParam` (or `VaryByCustom`) is not specified. What is used as the key?

By doing some quick tests, it seems to me like all the parameters of the action are used for the cache key. But how does the caching work when **some of the parameters are objects** (like these `foo`, `bar` parameters)? Does it use their hash code? Or does it use the form/querystring variables in the request instead?

I couldn't find sufficient documentation on this topic, however I think it's crucuial to understand these implementation details to avoid future bugs and misconceptions about the caching mechanism.

I am mostly interested in ASP.NET MVC version 5, however if anybody knows some history about the `OutputCache` attribute, I think this information is very useful as well.

Thanks for the answers or links!

Comment: Here is the relevant [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs) - see GetChildActionUniqueId and then GetUniqueIdFromActionParameters methods. If I am interpreting this correctly, all params for the request are used by their names

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks. As I understand it, there's some DescriptorUtil that actually takes the `foo` object and somehow generates Id from it. I found the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DescriptorUtil.cs), but I have no idea how it generates a string Id from a given object...

Comment: @Andrei: Also, by looking at the source code you posted, it seems that when no additional settings are specified, the `OutputCache` attribute seems to use `VaryByParam = "*"` ([line 23](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs#L23)). Do you understand it that way too?

Comment: @Andrei, @Tom: As the name suggests, `GetChildActionUniqueId` is only used for child actions; for top-level actions `OnResultExecuting` and `OutputCachedPage` are the relevant bits. The `OutputCachedPage` class inherits from [`System.Web.UI.Page`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/Page.cs), so you need to look at the `InitOutputCache` method there to start getting a feel for what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that OutputCacheAttribute works after model binding. 
Anyway I didn't found where it use actual request parameters from url.

What I found is that when it builds ChildAction cache key it use Action method parameters instead. It converts the value of parameter to String and do not serializes it.
And when you use class type parameter it just use the name of parameter and full name of the type to build the key:

```
string partString = Convert.ToString(part, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
builder.AppendFormat("[{0}]{1}", partString.Length, partString);
```

Solutions ?

1. Make all properties of class you need and coming from url as parameters of Action method.
2. Set VaryByParam = "prop1; prop2; ..." (I didn't test this case, can't confirm this works, but it should)

Comment: A bit late for the author, but for anybody asking the same question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to check it out. The solution in my case was actually to use VaryByCustom where I provided a custom implementation of how the string was composed. I prefer to have full control over this behavior.